# How to load remote database in cache, in python?

Tags: python, database, caching, cassandra, memcached

I want to load a database from a remote server to my memory/cache, so that I don't have to make network calls every time I want to use the database.

I am doing this in Python and the database is `cassandra`. How should I do it? I have heard about `memcached` and `beaker`. Which library is best for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get some data from a database, use the [pyodbc](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/) module. This module can be used to download data from a given table in a database. Answers can also be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451101/retrieving-data-from-sql-using-pyodbc).

An example how to connect:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLServer};SERVER=SQLSRV01;
                       DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SQL_QUERY")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

Comment: So this can load everything into my local cache irrespective of how large the database is?