# Retrieve data from sql server database using Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute the following script. but I don't get neither the desired results nor a error message ,and I can't figure out where I'm doing wrong.

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=mySRVERNAME;"
                        "Database=MYDB;"
                        "uid=sa;pwd=MYPWD;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select DISTINCT firstname,lastname,coalesce(middlename,\' \') as middlename from Person.Person')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

any ideas ? any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a fetch method along with cursor. For Example

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

**EDIT :**

The fetchall function returns all remaining rows in a list.

```
    If there are no rows, an empty list is returned. 
    If there are a lot of rows, *this will use a lot of memory.*
```

Unread rows are stored by the database driver in a compact format and are often sent in batches from the database server.

***Reading in only the rows you need at one time will save a lot of memory***.

If we are going to process the rows one at a time, **we can use the cursor itself as an interator**
Moreover we can simplify it since cursor.execute() always returns a cursor :

```
for row in cursor.execute("select bla, anotherbla from blabla"): 
    print row.bla, row.anotherbla
```

[Documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki)

Comment: it work but I want to know what is the difference between using only cursor and cursor.fetchall(), Because in some examples only cursor do the same as cursor.fetchall() ?

Comment: cursor is just a pointer to the database. After the executing a query we have explicitly fetch the rows that has been affected by the query so we use fetchall() method to do that.

Comment: I mean is it possible just to loop over the bare cursor object ?

Comment: as far as i know, you can't. It'll end up causing a RunTimeError

Comment: I'll keep searching for the reason, I know it's possible cuz I've been using it and also I know it's efficient with large results sets. once I found something I'll share it :),

Answer (score 0):

I found this information useful to retrieve data from SQL database to python as a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

con = pymssql.connect(server='use-et-aiml-cloudforte-aiops- db.database.windows.net',user='login_username',password='login_password',database='database_name')
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>"
cursor.execute(query)
df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
con.close()

df
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import mysql.connector as mc

# connection creation
conn = mc.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password')
print(conn)

#create cursor object

cur = conn.cursor()
print(cur)

cur.execute('show databases')

for i in cur:
    print(i)

query = "Select * from employee_performance.employ_mod_recent"
emp_data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
emp_data
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is specifically about SQL Server and PyODBC. MySQL and MySQL Connector are entirely irrelevant here.