# Retrieving Data from SQL Using pyodbc as list of dictionary

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have read the question ["Retrieving Data from SQL Using pyodbc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451101/retrieving-data-from-sql-using-pyodbc) and its answers. I am able to retrieve DB data using pyodbc:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print( row )
```

However I get only rows of data, in each row which looks like

```
A, B, C
D, E, F
```

I would like it like a dictionary where the title of each column is also indicated for example

```
studentName:A, studentAge:B, studentGrade: C
studentName:D, studentAge:E, studentGrade: F
```

and so on, how can I get a list of dictionaries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519385/output-pyodbc-cursor-results-as-python-dictionary has a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output pyodbc cursor results as python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519385/output-pyodbc-cursor-results-as-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following to get the expected results:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  print(row.studentName, row.studentAge, row.studentGrade)
```

Hope it helps.